# Inheritance of Enums

Tags: java, enums, java-8

To my understanding, Java enums are not extensible. So I wondered why enums are not final by definition. Just to make sure that I understand everything I had a look into the JLS 8 and found the following senentece:

> An enum declaration is implicitly final unless it contains at least one enum constant that has a class body (§8.9.1).

Does that imply that I can create an extensible enum constant with, for example, an own method declaration, field, static- or object initializer?

So far I didn't found a way which leads me to the conclusion that enums could be always implicitly final. Where am I wrong?

Comment: What does section 8.9.1 of the JLS tell you? (Since that's in the quote that you posted) -- (I'm quoting from it: "The optional class body of an enum constant implicitly defines an anonymous class declaration (§15.9.5) that extends the immediately enclosing enum type. The class body is governed by the usual rules of anonymous classes; in particular it cannot contain any constructors. Instance methods declared in these class bodies may be invoked outside the enclosing enum type only if they override accessible methods in the enclosing enum type (§8.4.8).")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the description says, enum constants can have their own body in which methods that are defined in the enum itself are overridden. For example:

```
public enum ExampleEnum {

    ONE,

    TWO {
        @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.println("Two");
        }
    };

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(name());
    }
}
```

In this example, the constant `TWO` has its own body with an overridden version of the `print()` method.

Note that it is not possible to extend an `enum` outside of the enum itself.

Comment: you can even make the print method abstract to force every enum to implement it (in case such a thing is needed).